# Is P implies not P a contradiction?

Tags: logic

I'm reading a textbook (*Discrete Mathematics: An Introduction for Software Engineers*, Mike Piff).

One of the exercises is to "show that the following are contradictions". Here's the one troubling me:

$$P \rightarrow \lnot P$$

I've written out the truth table to arrive at:

| $P$ | $\lnot P$ | $P \rightarrow \lnot P$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $T$ | $F$ | $F$ |
| $F$ | $T$ | $T$ |

I don't believe this is a contradiction because $P \rightarrow \lnot P$ is true when $P$ is false and I thought a contradiction always had to be false.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right there's something fishy: $P\to \neg P$ is just $\neg P$.

Comment: perhaps it’s a typo and they meant “$P$ and $\neg P$”

Comment: Seconding the above comment: a conditional sentence that has an atomic antecedent is vacuously true, so can't be a contradiction. $\quad$ EDIT: But @peek-a-boo, if that's the case, then how to show that something that is by definition true is true?

Comment: @ryang who knows, maybe they just want the student to practice writing out truth tables

Comment: you are correct, $P \to \neg P$ is not a contradiction. the textbook has made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view of the contradictions $B\wedge\neg B$ and $P\leftrightarrow\neg P$ already mentioned, it seems that he's gone through sort of *lapsus*:

[image]

The lapsus might be to suppose a case that $P$ holds only if $\neg P$ holds in the vein that

$$\Gamma\vdash P\implies\Gamma\vdash\neg P$$